# $\sum^{\frac{k}{2} - 1}_{i=0} x_{2i} = \left \lceil{\sum^{k-1}_{i=1} \frac{x_{i}}{2} }\right \rceil$ true for a sequence with the step propery?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Recall a step sequence is sequence with a sudden jump in its numbers. Formally:

[image]

I was trying to understand the  proof of the following lemma:

[image]

The first statement sort of makes sense to me. If there is no time when the sequence decreases by 1, then the sum of the even sequence is equal to the sum of the odd sequence which is equal to the sum the total sequence. This seems to only work for even numbers. For example if the sequence is {1,1,1} then, the even subsequence is {1,1} and the odd is {1} (assuming zero indexing) and the total of the whole is 3. Where 3/2 is not equal to 1 (the sum of the odd and even sequence).

Even when the length of the sequence is even, I can't make sense of the last statement. The proof isn't really a proof since it doesn't explain why those summations even hold...

Answer (score 0):

The lemma is false. Suppose that $k=3$ and $x_0=x_1=x_2=2$. Then

$$\sum_{i=0}^2\frac{x_i}2=\sum_{i=0}^21=3\;,$$

but the sum of the even subsequence is $2+2=4\ne\lceil 3\rceil$, and the sum of the odd subsequence is $2\ne\lfloor 3\rfloor$. There is also a minor error in the expression purporting to be the sum of the even subsequence: the upper limit of summation should be $\left\lfloor\frac{k-1}2\right\rfloor$. (The upper limit of summation for the odd subsequence really ought to be $\left\lfloor\frac{k}2\right\rfloor-1$, but this isn’t critical, since it’s how a sum to $\frac{k}2-1$ is generally understood when $k$ can be odd.)

What is true is that either the sums of the even and odd subsequences will be equal, in which case each will be half the sum of the whole sequence, or the sum of the even subsequence will exceed the some of the odd sequence by $x_{k-1}$ or by $x_0-x_{k-1}$.